# Problems trying to find nested directory using PHP

Tags: php, include

I'm a bit of a PHP newbie, but I'm trying to put some include files in a folder for tidiness. I've already been completely stumped by the whole root directory thing (I've tried `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and couldn't get that to work), but I'm confused why `include("../includes/sidebar.php");` doesn't work either. I can do `../sidebar.php` so going up a directory works, but going up and then in another directory doesn't.

No idea why, I've searched lots of forums and couldn't find any answers...

By the way, it's on a Linux server (streamline.net) - don't know anything other than that!

EDIT: Sorry I should've posted some server responses. If I try `<?php include("../includes/sidebar.php"); ?>` get this error:

```
Warning: include(../includes/sidebar.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/fhlinux162/u/___.org.uk/user/htdocs/ufradio/test.php on line 1

Warning: include(../includes/sidebar.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/fhlinux162/u/___.org.uk/user/htdocs/ufradio/test.php on line 1

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '../includes/sidebar.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear-php5') in /home/fhlinux162/u/___.org.uk/user/htdocs/ufradio/test.php on line 1
```

... even if the file exists.

Comment: What have you tried? What was your expected result? Can you post examples of what you would want to work?

Comment: sorry... edited and added an example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you try to load the page?  Do you get an error message?  A blank page?  Something else?  What is the directory structure and what are the file names?  Those would help us write an example for you.

When you are includes files (or otherwise traversing directories), the ".." means "up a level".

If we are running index.php, and you want to include other.php, just do:
    include('other.php');

If you wanted a file inside Subdirectory1, you would use:
    include('Subdirectory1/some_file.php');

If you were in Subdirectory1/some_file.php and you wanted to include other.php, you would go up a directory like:
    include("../other.php");

And if you were in Subdirectory1/some_file.php and you wanted to include yet_another_file.php from Subdirectory2, you would:
    include("../Subdirectory2/yet_another_file.php");

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi sorry, thanks for the advice. I've added an example above. I've tried the same path (which works), up a level (which also works), but going up a level and into another folder doesn't work, no matter what I call it.

Comment: Try `include('includes/sidebar.php');`

Comment: Hmm.  It's starting to look like there's just a typo, to me.  What kind of access to the server do you have?  Are you on a shell or just FTP?  If I were having the problem, the next thing I'd try to do is get a list of all the files and directories to see if maybe the includes folder is in the wrong place.

Comment: it's a website for a friend... It's on Streamline.net and I have FTP access to it. I've tried renaming the directory so it doesn't appear to be a typo, unless I'm not allowed to use words like "includes" or "inc"? The typo is not in the filename because it works fine when I put the file at the root (i.e. outside the "includes" folder).

Comment: Okay... you were right, a typo! It was a combination of not putting a forward slash before the includes (as per your DOCUMENT_ROOT) AND deciding to rename sidebar.php to sidebar.TXT. Thanks... I'm an idiot!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend running the following script:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
?>
```

This will help you see what, exactly, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] means on your server.  Sometimes it has a trailing / and sometimes you need to provide that on your own (this is set in Apache's configuration with the DocumentRoot directive.)

You might also have a permissions issue, so make sure that Apache has read access to the files you are trying to include.

Comment: it appears to respond exactly as I would expect: `/home/fhlinux162/u/___.org.uk/user/htdocs` which definitely looks like the root url to me. But it still doesn't work at the beginning of an include request.

Comment: So, to use that, you would have to include the slash after $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], otherwise you would run them together. Use `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/sidebar.php");`.  If you didn't have that slash, you would be telling it to find the file htdocsinclude/sidebar.php.

Comment: I tried that, and got the error: `Warning: include(/home/fhlinux162/u/___.org.uk/user/htdocs/includes/sidebar.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/fhlinux162/u/___.org.uk/user/htdocs/ufradio/test.php on line 1`

Comment: as put below... I tried all combinations EXCEPT the forward slash and getting it without the typo. Sorted now :) thanks for your help.